# CUDA Thrust and sort_by_key

Tags: sorting, cuda, permutation, thrust

I’m looking for a sorting algorithm on CUDA that can sort an array A of elements (double) and returns an array of keys B for that array A.
I know the `sort_by_key` function in the Thrust library but I want my array of elements A to remain unchanged.
What can I do?

My code is:

```
void sortCUDA(double V[], int P[], int N) {

        real_t *Vcpy = (double*) malloc(N*sizeof(double));
        memcpy(Vcpy,V,N*sizeof(double));

        thrust::sort_by_key(V, V + N, P);
        free(Vcpy);
}
```

i'm comparing the thrust algorithm against others that i have on sequencial cpu

```
N               mergesort       sortCUDA
113             0.000008        0.000010
226             0.000018        0.000016
452             0.000036        0.000020
905             0.000061        0.000034
1810            0.000135        0.000071
3621            0.000297        0.000156
7242            0.000917        0.000338
14484           0.001421        0.000853
28968           0.003069        0.001931
57937           0.006666        0.003939
115874          0.014435        0.008025
231749          0.031059        0.016718
463499          0.067407        0.039848
926999          0.148170        0.118003
1853998         0.329005        0.260837
3707996         0.731768        0.544357
7415992         1.638445        1.073755
14831984        3.668039        2.150179
115035495       39.276560       19.812200
230070990       87.750377       39.762915
460141980       200.940501      74.605219
```

Thrust performance is not bad, but I think if I use OMP can probably get easily a better CPU time

I think this is because to memcpy

SOLUTION:

```
void thrustSort(double V[], int P[], int N)
{
        thrust::device_vector<int> d_P(N);
        thrust::device_vector<double> d_V(V, V + N);
        thrust::sequence(d_P.begin(), d_P.end());

        thrust::sort_by_key(d_V.begin(), d_V.end(), d_P.begin());

        thrust::copy(d_P.begin(),d_P.end(),P);
}
```

where V is a my double values to sort

Comment: Make a copy of A before sorting?  Also, if you are a thrust user, you may want to consider joining the [thrust google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/thrust-users).

Comment: Yes, I did, but the performance was much reduced

Comment: Perhaps you should post some code and answer the questions about sizes.  I would expect the cost of the sorting operation to be significantly higher than the cost for a vector copy.

Comment: Where you intend to use OMP?

Comment: on my CPU algorithm mergesort

Comment: It looks to me like you're not using the CUDA device at all.  Thrust has host-side algorithms and device-side algorithms.  Also, you said adding the vector copy made it "so much slower".  But I don't see data or evidence that you've timed the difference.

Comment: not be using the cuda device at all? mmm, why that may be happening? O_o

Comment: You'll need to learn more about [thrust](http://thrust.github.com/), perhaps take a look at the [quick start guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide).  Vectors can live on the host or device.  If you pass vectors (or pointers to arrays) that are host-based, Thrust will use a host-based algorithm to sort (leaving the GPU idle).  If you pass vectors or pointers that are device-based, Thrust will use a device-based algorithm to sort (i.e. on the GPU). Your code that you posted gives me the impression that your pointers are host based.

Comment: Is true, i never used Thrust before
Thanks, i'm gonna read little more about pointer device

Comment: I'm actually impressed that Thrust is faster than your mergesort, even for sizes as small as 226, especially since you are adding in the cost of the vector copy (don't know if you are doing that with your mergesort -- you didn't post that code.)  If you use the thrust device sort, there will be a cost to copy the vectors to the device.  This will penalize your small-size sorts but probably give a substantial improvement on the large size ones.    Also, [the development version of thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust) should be substantially faster at sorting.

Comment: Even if you are sure you are running on the GPU, since you haven't even told us what GPU and CPU you are running on, we can't really surmise whether these are expected performance or not.  You could be running on a 1-SM laptop GPU and so a large speedup would not be expected, for example.

Comment: Indeed i was using cpu thrust, I fixed it and now the speedup is more than 20x better than cpu thrust
Thank you, very much :D

Answer (score 2):

You can modify comparison operator to sort keys instead of values. @Robert Crovella correctly pointed that a raw device pointer cannot be assigned from the host. The modified algorithm is below:

```
struct cmp : public binary_function<int,int,bool>
{
  cmp(const double *ptr) : rawA(ptr) { }

  __host__ __device__ bool operator()(const int i, const int j) const 
  {return rawA[i] > rawA[j];}

   const double *rawA; // an array in global mem
}; 

void sortkeys(double *A, int n) {
  // move data to the gpu
  thrust::device_vector<double> devA(A, A + n);
  double *rawA = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(devA.data());

  thrust::device_vector<int> B(n);
  // initialize keys
  thrust::sequence(B.begin(), B.end());
  thrust::sort(B.begin(), B.end(), cmp(rawA));
  // B now contains the sorted keys
 }
```

And here is alternative with arrayfire. Though I am not sure which one is more efficient since arrayfire solution uses two additional arrays:

```
void sortkeys(double *A, int n) {
   af::array devA(n, A, af::afHost);
   af::array vals, indices;
   // sort and populate vals/indices arrays
   af::sort(vals, indices, devA);
   std::cout << devA << "\n" << indices << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work.  But apart from that, will this work if the keys are not the sequence (0, 1, 2, ...) ? Presumably the general case of sort_by_key does not require this of keys.

Comment: In addition, I don't think this line of code is doing what you want it to: `rawA = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(devA.data());`  I could not get it to work.  It does compile, but thrust throws an exception if you try to dereference rawA after that line.  I was able to get an alternate version working using basically the same method but cudaMemcpyToSymbol, instead of that line.

Comment: huh you are right, assigning a raw device pointer on the host does not make much sense.. but thanks for providing a working example. I am not sure what you mean by keys are not the sequence (0, 1, 2, ...) ? Having a sequence [0, 1, 2, .. n] you can provide a one-to-one mapping to any other sequence of keys

Comment: The general thrust sort_by_key does  not place any requirements on the keys that they be 0, 1, 2.  Take a look at the example [here](http://thrust.github.com/doc/group__sorting.html#gae3829160fc6160d083f79a34e67bd452). Your method would not work on that example with those keys.  It's true that if you sort a generated set of indices that you can (later) rearrange a set of keys, but whether this is any faster than just making a copy of the original data set and doing a sort, I'm not sure.

Comment: @asm I think this line: `rawA = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(devA.data());`   should be something like this: `double *  rawA = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(devA.data());`   Anyway what you have posted now doesn't compile for me (rawA is undefined on that line) but if I make that change it works.

Comment: ops, you are right, i missed the declaration. I compiled the algorithm on my machine and it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

How large is this array? The most efficient way, in terms of speed, will likely be to just duplicate the original array before sorting, if the memory is available.

Comment: that's what i did on first, but was so much slower

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer provided by @asm (I wasn't able to get it working), this code seemed to work for me, and does sort only the keys.  However, I believe it is limited to the case where the keys are in sequence 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ... corresponding to the (double) values.  Since this is a "index-value" sort, it could be extended to the case of an arbitrary sequence of keys, perhaps by doing an indexed copy.  However I'm not sure the process of generating the index sequence and then rearranging the original keys will be any faster than just copying the original value data to a new vector (for the case of arbitrary keys).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>

using namespace std;

__device__  double *rawA; // an array in global mem

struct cmp : public binary_function<int, int, bool>
{
  __host__ __device__  bool operator()(const int i, const int j) const
  {return ( rawA[i] < rawA[j]);}
};

void sortkeys(double *A, int n) {
  // move data to the gpu
  thrust::device_vector<double> devA(A, A + n);
//  rawA = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&(devA[0]));
  double *test = raw_pointer_cast(devA.data());
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(rawA, &test, sizeof(double *));

  thrust::device_vector<int> B(n);
  // initialize keys
  thrust::sequence(B.begin(), B.end());
  thrust::sort(B.begin(), B.end(), cmp());
  // B now contains the sorted keys
  thrust::host_vector<int> hostB = B;
  for (int i=0; i<hostB.size(); i++)
    std::cout << hostB[i] << " ";
  std::cout<<std::endl;
  for (int i=0; i<hostB.size(); i++)
    std::cout << A[hostB[i]] << " ";
  std::cout<<std::endl;
 }


int main(){

  double C[] = {0.7, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 1.2, -0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 10.0};
  sortkeys(C, 9);
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```