# thrust::sort_by_key: How to store result in separate array?

Tags: sorting, cuda, thrust

I am currently sorting values by key the following way

```
thrust::sort_by_key(thrust::device_ptr<int>(keys), 
                    thrust::device_ptr<int>(keys + numKeys),
                    thrust::device_ptr<int>(values);
```

which sorts the "values" array according to "keys".

Is there a way to leave the the "values" array untouched and instead store the result of sorting "values" in a separate array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515308/cuda-thrust-and-sort-by-key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to do what you are asking. You have two options to functionally achieve the same thing.

The first is make a copy of the values array before the call, leaving you with a sorted and unsorted version of the original data. So your example becomes

```
thrust::device_vector<int> values_sorted(thrust::device_ptr<int>(values),
                                     thrust::device_ptr<int>(values + numKeys));

thrust::sort_by_key(thrust::device_ptr<int>(keys), 
                    thrust::device_ptr<int>(keys + numKeys),
                    values_sorted.begin());
```

The second alternative is *not to pass the values array to the sort at all*. Thrust has a very useful permutation iterator which allows for seamless permuted access to an array without modifying the order in which that array is stored (so an iterator based gather operation, if you will). To do this, create an index vector and sort that by key instead, then instantiate a permutation iterator with that sorted index, something like

```
typedef thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator iit;

thrust::device_vector<int> index(thrust::make_counting_iterator(int(0)),
                                 thrust::make_counting_iterator(int(numKeys));    

thrust::sort_by_key(thrust::device_ptr<int>(keys), 
                    thrust::device_ptr<int>(keys + numKeys),
                    index.begin());


thrust::permutation_iterator<iit,iit> perm(thrust::device_ptr<int>(values),
                                           index.begin());
```

Now `perm` will return `values` in the `keys` sorted order held by `index` without ever changing the order of the original data.

[standard disclaimer: all code written in browser, never compiled or tested. Use at own risk]

Comment: Thank you for your response! I thought of doing it the first way before, but I was afraid of the overhead that comes with it. I will try your second approach and see how it turns out. However, as thrust does not provide such functionality, I am afraid that implementing radix sort by oneself might be the fastest solution to this problem ...